# NullPointerException from a bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, transactions, android-menu

I keep getting a `NullPointer` from my bundle but it only started when I changed how I was manipulating a fragment to I think it has to do with the transaction in the menu but I can't find anything on what the problem could be.

This is the error (It's long but this has the two spots it shows to have crashed at).

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference 01-22 13:58:05.652 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at com.nyc.javadontlie.LoggingFragment.onViewCreated(LoggingFragment.java:59) 01-22 13:58:05.652 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1651) 01-22 13:58:05.652 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1390) 01-22 13:58:05.652 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1640) 01-22 13:58:05.653 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1896) 01-22 13:58:05.653 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3673) 01-22 13:58:05.653 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111) 01-22 13:58:05.653 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338) 01-22 13:58:05.653 28461-28461/com.nyc.javadontlie 
    W/System
```

My Logging/fragment

```
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.annotation.Nullable; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager; 
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; 
import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    import com.nyc.javadontlie.controller.LoggingAdapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Collections;

    import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


    /**  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.  */

    public class LoggingFragment extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private ArrayList<String> logArrayList;
        private Bundle bundle;

        public LoggingFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logging, container, false);
            bundle = getArguments();

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            SharedPreferences gameInfo = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("GameModel",MODE_PRIVATE);
            logArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {


                String gameName;
                if (!bundle.get(Constants.LOGGING_FRAG_KEY).equals(null)) {
                    gameName = bundle.get(Constants.LOGGING_FRAG_KEY).toString();
                } else {
                    gameName = "";
                }
                if (gameInfo.getString("StringLog" + gameName, null) != null) {
                    String[] stringSet = gameInfo.getString("StringLog" + gameName, null).trim().split(",");
                    Collections.addAll(logArrayList, stringSet);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_logging);
            LoggingAdapter adapter = new LoggingAdapter(logArrayList);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        } }
```

This is where the transaction is made.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection



    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.log_text_menu:

            LoggingFragment fragment = (LoggingFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if (fragment == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Log was Clicked");
                addLogToShared();
                fragment = new LoggingFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(fragment_container,fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack("LogFrag");
                transaction.show(fragment);
                transaction.commit();

            } else if (fragment.isVisible()){
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.hide(fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            } else if (!fragment.isVisible()) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.show(fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }


            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void addLogToShared() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = gameInfo.edit();

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s1: logArrayList) {
        s.append(s1).append(",");
    }
    editor.putString("StringLog" + gameName, s.toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling methods on the bundle when it is null.

Therefore first check if bundle is not null then proceed